# How recover php-fpm conf.d files?

Tags: apache-http-server, php

I'm trying to upgrade PHP with `php-fpm` from 8.1 to 8.2.

By mistake, I've deleted the files inside `/etc/php/8.2/fpm/conf.d`

I've tried to restart `php8.2-fpm` and Apache2 server, re-install `php-fpm`, but those aren't generated again.

I did see they were symlinks from `/etc/php/8.2/mods-available/`, so I've tried to re-create them manually.

The `phpinfo()` shows the .ini files as loaded:
[image]

However, I'm having having problems with the site running on the server (Drupal one).

If I do e.g. `drush cr` and I get:

> [preflight] Class "DOMDocument" does not exist

Anf from [this question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/218271/74024) it seems the `php-xml` isn't actually loaded.

Therefore, I get I did something wrong.

Any suggestions?

Comment: In the future, I would strongly recommend having `etckeeper` installed – keeps automatic Git commits of /etc both daily and before any package upgrades.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just uninstall everything and then reinstall it again. That should completely reset things to square one.